# Can rhandsontable values be edited and saved without shiny?

Tags: r, data-binding, dataframe, shiny

The documentation for rhandsontable says that the data table produced from the source dataframe is editable by default http://rpubs.com/jrowen/intro_rhandsontable.

Yet, while the table created by the following code can be edited, there is no way to observe the edits and incorporate them back into the source dataFrame.

```
library(rhandsontable)

DF = data.frame(val = 1:10, bool = TRUE, big = LETTERS[1:10],
                small = letters[1:10],
                dt = seq(from = Sys.Date(), by = "days", length.out = 10),
                stringsAsFactors = F)

rhandsontable(DF, rowHeaders = NULL)
```

I am an R newbie, and have a very tenuous grasp of how data bindings work.  My question: is it possible to observe and incorporate the edits into the source dataFrame without using Shiny?

I do not want to use Shiny, because as I understand it, shiny apps are blocking.

Comment: If no reactive context is setup, how do you plan on telling R it should magically retrieve the data?

Comment: "There is no way to set up a reactive context in R, so the answer  is no, rhandsontable cannot be edited and saved without Shiny."   Do I have that interpretation correct?  If so, you can submit this as an answer and I will accept it.  Thanks for clarifying!